# Export Sentinel RGB Image openable in Google Earth Pro

Tags: google, sentinel

I'm trying to export a Sentinel RGB Image to open in Google Earth Pro.

The resulting GeoTIFF image opens OK in QGIS but it shows blank when opening in Google Earth Pro.

Does anyone knows how to prepare in GEE a Sentinel RGB Image so it can be displayed properly Google Earth Pro?